# Как взять число у определенного input

Tags: jquery

У меня есть каталог, в каталоге есть кнопка , в кнопке есть `input`  и две кнопки которые увеличивают значения и уменьшают значение в `input`. Но `input ов` может быть много! И я решил их отследить по `date-item`. Тоесть при клике на кнопку `(+ или -)` я получаю `date-item`. И теперь я получаю число с `input` у которого тоже `date-item`.

```
$(".inc").click(function () { // тут я обрабатываю клик
    date_item = $(this).attr('date-item'); // узнаю какое число в date-item
    valueProductCount = $('input.fieldCount').val();//тут я получаю число с input
    alert(valueProductCount);//вывожу
});
```

поначалу хотел так сделать на получение числа с `input`

valueProductCount = $('input.fieldCount').eq(date_items).val();

> но я не получаю требуемое число!
>
> Как можно получить число? Или как можно обойтись без `date-item` - а
>   точнее как определять какой по счёту класс в массиве чтобы потом к
>   нему обращаться!

```
<div class="myBlockByPLT">
  <button type="button" class="but counterBut dec" date-item="1">-</button>
  <input type="text" class="field fieldCount" date-item="1" value="1" data-min="1" data-max="11">
  <button type="button" class="but counterBut inc" date-item="1">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: добавьте в вопрос кусок разметки для кнопки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это дело можно организовать, доставая нужный элемент в зависимости от кликнутой `$(this)`

`.siblings()` дает список всех элементов одинакового "уровня" с данным элементом. А если указать в нем конкретный класс - достанет нужный инпут. Покликайте:

```js
$('.inc').on('click', function(){
  var x = $(this).siblings('.num').val();
  $(this).siblings('.num').val( ++x );
});

$('.dec').on('click', function(){
  var x = $(this).siblings('.num').val();
  x = (x > 1) ? (--x) : 0; // Ограничение на отрицательные числа, например
  $(this).siblings('.num').val( x );
});
```

```css
.block { margin: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">
  <button class="dec">-</button>
  <input class="num" value="0">
  <button class="inc">+</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <button class="dec">-</button>
  <input class="num" value="0">
  <button class="inc">+</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <button class="dec">-</button>
  <input class="num" value="0">
  <button class="inc">+</button>
</div>
```

P.s. Еще можете поискать `parent()`, `children()`, `next()`, `prev()`, `closest()`, `find()`. Сильно помогают ориентироваться с элементами)

P.s.-2 Перевод в 'чистый' JS, не так уж и длинно:

```js
var inc = document.querySelectorAll('.inc');
var dec = document.querySelectorAll('.dec');

for( var i = 0; i < inc.length; i++ ){
  // Там могло быть 2 цикла, но кол-во кнопок всегда одинаковое, можно напихать в один.
  inc[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    var num = this.parentNode.querySelector('.num'); // Без All - первый найденный
    num.value = +num.value + 1; 
    // Плюсик перед num.value превращает его в число. val() делает это за нас. 
    // Без плюса, '0' + 1 станет 01 вместо 1.
  });
 
  dec[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    var num = this.parentNode.querySelector('.num');
    num.value = (num.value > 1) ? (num.value - 1) : 0;
  });
 
}
```

```css
.block { margin: 5px; }
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <button class="dec">-</button>
  <input class="num" value="0">
  <button class="inc">+</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <button class="dec">-</button>
  <input class="num" value="0">
  <button class="inc">+</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <button class="dec">-</button>
  <input class="num" value="0">
  <button class="inc">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ох, OPTIMUS PRIME. Уже второй раз меня спасаешь, разгадываешь мои загадки) И действительно с версткой угадал)

Comment: @Максим Сиваконь *добавил "перевод" в JS))